# aspnet mvc system no user when AuthenticateRequest event raised

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, authentication, asp.net-web-api

I have an existing mvc webapi system that uses no authentication or authorization and I am attempting to add Windows authentication in.  I approached this by creating a new simplified system with a single controller returning just static data.

The new system is set up to use Windows authentication, and as a result when I hook into the `Application_AuthenticateRequest` the `HttpContext.Current.User` is not null and has a populated `Identity` property with the correct `WindowsPrincipal` for the user sending the request.

In the existing system, when I amend the `web.config` to match the new (working) system all incoming requests have a null `HttpContext.Current.User` in `Application_AuthenticateRequest`.

I saw a post suggesting that I use the `Application_AuthorizeRequest` event handler as it is fired later in the pipeline.  As expected the `HttpContext.Current.User` is not null at this point, however the `Identity` property of this is set as having an impersonation level of `Anonymous` and importantly is not authenticated.

I assume that my production system that I am trying to add authentication to is somehow configured to not use impersonation, yet my new proof of concept system is.  As a result the Authenticate stage of the pipeline is adding an anonymous user to the HttpContext which is what I am seeing in the Authorize stage of the pipeline.

**My question is how do I configure my production system to use impersonation** so that I can access the user that has sent the request?

Please note that the system is deployed to an intranet so the Windows identity of the user is all I need and gives sufficient security.

my web config contains the following:

```
<system.web>
 <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.6.1" />
 <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6.1" />
 <authentication mode="Windows" />
 <identity impersonate="true" />
 <httpModules>
 </httpModules>
</system.web>
```

in both systems (production and POC) and I have tried removing the `<identity/>` element from both and it appears to have no effect.

At this stage I am hosting only in IISExpress through VS2015

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this was all down to IIS configuration.

When hosting a site within VS2015 using IISExpress, the applicationhost.config file that is used by IISExpress is one stored locally with the soure.  Specifically in the $(SolutionDir).vs\config folder.

The config for my production system had windows authentication disabled and anonymous authentication enabled, and the POC system had the reverse.  Changing this config file has fixed my problems, now the question is whether this will work on another user's PC or will an incorrect applicationhost.config file be generated??